# How to get value from char pointer member of a structure modified in another function

Tags: c++

I passed a structure pointer to a function. What I need is to get the string "connection refused"(return from ssh_get_error()) in the main function.

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

typedef struct rtns {
    bool state;
    char* desc;
} rtns;

int connect_host(rtns *con_host) {
    const char* desc;
    char desc2[1000];
    ssh_session my_ssh_session;
    int rc;
    my_ssh_session = ssh_new();
    if (my_ssh_session == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    ssh_options_set(my_ssh_session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "localhost");
    rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
    if (rc != SSH_OK) {
        (*con_host).state = false;
        desc = ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session);
        strcpy(desc2, ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
        (*con_host).desc = strdup(desc2);
        cout << "from connect_host function->" <<con_host->desc << "\n";
    } else {
        (*con_host).state = true;
    }

    ssh_disconnect(my_ssh_session);
    ssh_free(my_ssh_session);
}

int main() {
    rtns con_host;
    rtns *p = (rtns*) malloc(sizeof(struct rtns));
    p = (rtns*) malloc(20);
    connect_host(&con_host);
    cout << "from main function->" << *(con_host.desc) << "\n\n";
}
```

Output-

```
from connect_host function->Connection refused
from main function->C
```

The problem is that i am only getting one character "C" in the main function. I have some idea that I am doing memory allocation wrong but i have no idea how to do it correctly. I also tried to shift the malloc allocation in con_host function but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you are printing. You pass to the stream a `char`, not a `char *`:

```
cout << "from main function->" << *(con_host.desc) << "\n\n";
// *(con_host.desc) = *(char *) = char
// Above is a simplification but you get the point.
```

So long as `con_host.desc` is a null terminated c string you can print it like this:

```
cout << "from main function->" << con_host.desc << "\n\n";
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/pDDGlN)

Comment: So that malloc part is not even necessary? I re-run it and it is working without it. But I found on Internet that character pointer in a structure needed  to assign memory first. Can you please explain?

Comment: @RishabhSoni You *do* assign it some memory. Read about [strdup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup). It will create the memory of the string for you, in fact you need to call free on it later to clear the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's not memory allocation error. It's caused by the output statement. Change to

```
      cout << "from main function->" << con_host.desc << "\n\n";
```